# How Kosmos File System (KFS) handle reflection?

Tags: c++, distributed-filesystem

Happy Easter!

I am writing an distributed file system in C++. And, for control it fully, I wrote my own RPC. The last pending question for this RPC framework is reflection, as C++ doesn't provide it.

I know KFS is a DFS written in c++, but I don't know its implementation, so I turn to you kind and knowledgeable people.

I guess it may have some way to handle its RPC, isn't it? Does it use reflection somehow? If it's not using reflection, is there any other c++ based distributed applications using it. And how they use it?

Please feel free to advice, I like ideas.

Cheers,
Elton

Comment: Is this the [Kosmos File System](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kosmosfs/) found at SourceForge and previously at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/kosmosfs/)?  With [QFS](https://github.com/quantcast/qfs) (Quantcast File System) as the replacement for KFS on Google Code?  You say you're writing a DFS, but then seem to reference a DFS written by others.  So, I'm rather confused about what's going on.  I'm also not sure how reflection would affect a file system, but that is probably because I'm not familiar with KFS (nor all that familiar with reflection).

Comment: A fairly well-known RPC model on top of C++ is Microsoft (D)COM. It handles reflection by requiring COM classes to derive from `class IUnknown` and in particular handle `IUnknown::QueryInterface(GUID)`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about KFS/QFS. But the way to go into Reflection in C++ would be to consider LLVM.